# Laravel web route variable is not returning as supposed

Tags: php, routes, arguments, laravel-5.3, url-parameters

I have the following route :

```
    Route::get('/web/{cat_id?}/{post_type}','WebPostsController@index')
->where('post_type', '(pictures|videos|links|companies)')
->name('post_index');
```

Controller file :

```
 public function index($post_type,$post_id = null,$cat_id = null)
    {

        dd($post_type);
}
```

When access the URL /public/web/15/videos
It return '15' which is supposed to return {post_type} value (videos) while it returning the {cat_id?} value.

Comment: What is post_id in index method ?

Comment: Do you have any group before routes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables passed in to the action have to follow the definition in the route.
That is, in your case, you expect the `cat_id` first, then the `post_type` which means that you will have to define the method as:

```
public function index($cat_id, $post_type) { }
```

Furthermore, I expect that you will have some issues with it still, cause you can not have an optional parameter and then a forced parameter. So either move the `$cat_id` param as a optional to the end of the route and use `$post_type` before (`/public/web/videos/15`) or make both forced.